# How to always use HttpServletRequestWrapper?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

With spring-boot-web

Fellow guides, Using HttpServletRequestWrapper to re-read request body is easy like this:

```java
 public static class CachedHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
            System.out.println("getInputStream");
            return new CachedHttpServletInputStream(this.data);
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedReader getReader() {
            System.out.println("getReader");
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
        }
}
```

But in some case this going wrong:

If controller accept @RequestParam and POST with form (mutlipart or url-encode) will cause no such parameter.

Then I make some debug:

When url-encode: It's not using getInputStream or getReader, Its invoke getParameterMap and diginto this, The internal method not using wrapped stream, So the origin stream is readed so there nothing to read anymore

[image: Stream read internaly]

When mutlipart-form: Tomcat read the post body into cache files and ignore wrapper stream, then cause same result;

So the question is: How to make body readable in any case ?

Comment: Unless you extend `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` and override `Connector#createRequest`, you can't. BTW: what would be the purpose of parsing data that the server already parsed for you?

Comment: For record body data audit them in future. Thx